# Error in creating a Development Server with Vagrant and Virtual box

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, vagrant

I'm quite new to web development and creating a website using django and a development server using vagrant and virtual box.I have defined a vagrant file for the server to use the base image or box ubuntu/bionic64
and later modified it also

```
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
 # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
 # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

 # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
 # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
 config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
 config.vm.box_version = "~> 20200304.0.0"

 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000

 config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   systemctl disable apt-daily.service
   systemctl disable apt-daily.timer

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y python3-venv zip
   touch /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
   if ! grep -q PYTHON_ALIAS_ADDED /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases; then
     echo "# PYTHON_ALIAS_ADDED" >> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
     echo "alias python='python3'" >> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
   fi
 SHELL
end
```

But when I'm trying to create the development server by using the command `vagrant up` in git bash  its showing the error

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'ubuntu/bionic64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: ~> 20200304.0.0
The box 'ubuntu/bionic64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/bionic64"]
Error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

What should I do to clear this error??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked and found the actual problem was the windows firewall which was creating all the trouble by interfering with the SSL certificate

Answer (score 1):

change the second line to

```
config.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"
```

I had the same error. I am not sure how to get to the box you have in your
vagrantfile. Logged into hashicorp site and found a suitable box for me to use.
You can do the same if the above is not suitable to you.

Comment: did you used any other base image also instead of hashicorp/bionic64??

Comment: several. examples -  generic/ubuntu1604,  roboxes/alpine310. etc.
You can search for most downloaded, recent ubuntu image from vagrant cloud (the url is in your vagrant file above) and try them.
The particular box you tried to use is not available from vagrant cloud, i think.